# Focus and keypress issue with eclipse swt Textfield and swing JTextField

Tags: eclipse, swing, focus, swt, keypress

In our test program we added one textfield from swt (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text), one textfield from *swing* and one from the *awt*. 
We use java 1.8 latest and SWT library we tested are 3.7 and 4.3

The problems/issues are:

- If you focus to the swt textfield, and then focus to the swing text field, you can not type any character which needs **alt key** combination, for example alt+q (@) or alt+<> (|) character, but you can type any other characters. If you focus to awt textfield and focus to swing textfield back, you are able to start typing @ again.
- If you focus to the swt textfield, and then focus to the awt textfield, and then focus to swing text field, no problems occur.
- The issue arises when you *focus from swt to swing textfield.*

You may ask that mixing them in same appl is a bad idea. I added the awt text field for testing purpose only, in our application we do not have any awt component. But we have to embed an HTML viewer into our application which is called DJBrowser (https://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject) and it is SWT based. (It uses eclipse swt Browser instance) If you navigate to a page with an input for example google.com or set its HTML content to an input and focus that input and you then focus to swing textfields of our application, user can not type @ character anymore. (The problem is cleared if you perform alt+tab or show an dummy JOptionMessage).
The problem is not djbrowsers fault, it is caused by the swt and started after Java 1.7.

Any idea to solve the issue?

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried to use WebView from JavaFX instead of DJBrowser?

Comment: Yes we tried, but WebView is not  real browser and fails on complex pages. There is an also a commercial option using chromium, it works fine as an option. But webview is not 100% chromium.